# video stream from vlc to android, video missing

Tags: android, rtsp, vlc

I'm trying to stream a video from VLC to an HTC G1. After several "this should work" I found a sout-chain that allowed me to watch the stream via VLC. I am also able to hear the audio on the android.

The sout-chain I'm currently using:

```
vlc some_file.mp4 -I http --sout "#transcode{soverlay,ab=128,samplerate=44100,channels=2,acodec=mp4a,vcodec=h264,width=480,height=270,vfilter="canvas{width=480,height=270,aspect=16:9}",fps=25,vb=800,venc=x264{level=12,no-cabac,subme=20,threads=4,bframes=0,min-keyint=1,keyint=50}}:gather:rtp{mp4a-latm,sdp=rtsp://0.0.0.0:5554/stream.sdp}"
```

That's what I'm doing on the droid:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://<local_ip>:5554/stream.sdp"));
    vv.start();
}
```

I tried to keep it as minimal as possible (this is actually an example I found in another thread here).
I also tried using MediaPlayer:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("rtsp://<local_ip>:5554/stream.sdp"));
mp.setDisplay(vv.getHolder());
mp.start();
```

I use setDisplay(SurfaceHolder) cause someone mentioned MediaPlayer otherwise wont know what display to use.

Any idea what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Edit: I hinted the the file with MP4Box

Comment: Switched to Darwin Streaming Server, works fine. Tested on an LG Optimus Speed and discovered that this phone plays video and audio just as expected. So I consider my problem solved.

Comment: I have also been unsuccessful getting VLC to stream to android devices. The built in media player should support rtsp urls so you should be able to open the stream direcly from the URL bar in the web browser. If anyone know the magical sout parameter set to get VLC straeming to Android working please post a reply here!

Answer (score 0):

First, I think there's problem with your audio encoder, it shows "MPEG-1/2 Video" is not an audio encoder, would you please try "mpga"?

and another problem is you are trying to fit the frames into a specified size, width=480,height=270, could you delete this part?

my command works:

vlc /Users/chenyu/Sites/BBC.mp4 -I http --sout "#transcode{soverlay,ab=128,samplerate=44100,channels=2,acodec=mpga,vcodec=h264,fps=25,vb=800,venc=x264{level=1,no-cabac,subme=20,threads=4,bframes=0,min-keyint=1,keyint=50}}:gather:rtp{mp4a-latm,sdp=rtsp://10.0.1.2:5554/stream.sdp}"

also could you try the following code on android side?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);

        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
        vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
        vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);

        vidView.setVideoPath("rtsp://10.0.1.2:5554/stream.sdp");

        vidView.start();
        }
```